# how to loop over the pixels using 2D array?

Tags: processing

For example:

```java
loadPixels(); 
for (int i = 0; i < 240; i++) 
{
  for(int j =0; i < 240; j++)
  {
    color p = pixels[i][j];    // ERROR : The type of the expression must be an array 
                                  type but it resolved to int


    float cRed = 0.2989 * red(p);
    float cGreen = 0.5870 * green(p); 
    float cBlue = 0.1140 * blue(p);
    pixels[i][j] = color(cRed, cGreen, cBlue);
  }
}
updatePixels();
```

Comment: What is the type of "pixels".  If it was color[][] then I think the code should work.  From your description I think it is of type int[][].

Comment: This line is probably going to bomb out:
`for(int j =0; i < 240; j++)` (Note the *i* in the middle)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [pixels documentation](http://www.processing.org/reference/pixels.html), pixels is a one dimensional array.  So you'll probably need to do something like

```
int row = i;
int col = j;
int offset = row * width + col;
color p = pixels[offset];
```

Not sure how you get the width of the window, but that's what you'd need to do (assuming that the rows are stored in order in the array).

Comment: This is exactly right, and they are stored in order.  Also, width is a system variable that always stores the width of the window.

Comment: Phew, looks like my mind and the Processing authors worked the same way.  Nice :)