# Can JavaScript canvas be manipulated like a bitmap, and is it optimized for that use?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, bitmap

Can a JavaScript canvas be manipuled like a standard bitmap (accessing/modifying a pixel and getting it's size)? Is this use optimized, or would it be faster to manipulate normal 2d arrays of pixels and draw over canvas when you need it?

Comment: This article might answer your question: http://beej.us/blog/data/html5s-canvas-2-pixel/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Absolutely yes! Please have a look here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Canvas_tutorial/Pixel_manipulation_with_canvas

As for your second question, as per the pixels documentation, pixels is a one dimensional array. You'll need to do your own 2 x 2 hoopla for a 2d way.

Taken from a previous SO answer by [I82Much](https://stackoverflow.com/users/155392/i82much) (works dandy for me):

```
int row = i;
int col = j;
int offset = row * width + col;
color p = pixels[offset];
```

More here: [how to loop over the pixels using 2D array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5315265/how-to-loop-over-the-pixels-using-2d-array)

and here: http://www.processing.org/reference/pixels.html

Answer (score 1):

You can get an array of pixel data from the canvas context using [getImageData()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/CanvasRenderingContext2D#getImageData%28%29). Bear in mind that each pixel takes-up 4 spaces in the array (for red, green, blue and alpha). Then, once you've altered the array to your liking, you can use [putImageData()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/CanvasRenderingContext2D#putImageData%28%29) to put the data back.